# Send azure monitor alert to slack not working

Tags: azure, slack, azure-alerts

I am sure this has been asked many times but am unable to find relevant answer. Is there any way to send Azure monitor alerts to slack via Logic apps or some other way. I have found this template - https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/demos/alert-to-slack-with-logic-app and integrated it into my azure system  but it is not working.

Have tried some work around mentioned at - https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/issues/3319 but all in vain

Direct Webhook from action group using slack incoming webhook is not supported , as azure sends alert using its own schema.

Any input is highly appreciated ...

Answer (score 5):

Azure Logic Apps is definitely an option, but if you are not needing complicated workflows, just send the alert directly from Azure Monitor to a Slack channel.  You can do this by generating a unique email for the Slack channel and using that email in your Azure Monitor alert action group settings.  Another option would be to send the alert to your company alert email inbox and have it automatically forwarded to that Slack channel email address. With this approach you completely remove the dependency and complexity of Azure Logic Apps.

https://slack.com/help/articles/206819278-Send-emails-to-Slack#h_01F4WDZG8RTCTNAMR4KJ7D419V